# /etc/inittab not found in rpi

Tags: raspbian, serial

I am new to the RPi, and I want to link it to the arduino Mega through Serial communication with a rpi b 2, so i bought a logic converter, and did wiring and everything, but now i wanted to make some modifications in the system files to able the serial communication /etc/inittab file but I can't find it, I did modify the /boot/cmdline.txt I really appreciate your help Thank you

Comment: I don't know the exact answer, but you can find a description of serial consoles in the systemd 'world' here: http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/serial-console.html

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of Raspbian (8, aka. jessie) uses [systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) instead of [SysVinit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init#SYSV), which is what `/etc/inittab` belonged to, and older documentation will not reflect this.

There is no exact equivalent so how to do what you want depends upon specifically what it is you want to do.

Comment: Thank you for your answer well I want to make the information exchange between the Rpi and arduino through the serial bus Tx/Rx, and through the tutorials I have found one, but claims that I have to disable the boot serial communication, and to do that I have to do some edits in the file systems like /etc/inittab and /biit/cmdline.txt, do you have any idea how I can proceed ?

Comment: I don't think you have to do anything else in that case.  I don't see anything in the default systemd config to do with this, and `raspi-config` (which you can use to enable/disable the serial console) doesn't do anything other than alter `cmdline.txt`.